# Upgrade i386 from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, 32-bit

I try upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 and receive the message: "There will not be any further Ubuntu releases for this system 'i386' architecture.". Can I upgrade? What can I do?

Comment: No you can not upgrade. Ubuntu dropped 32bit support.  If your cpu is not able for 64bit `grep flags /proc/cpuinfo `

Comment: New releases are no longer built for 32-bit i386 architecture - so you can't upgrade beyond 18.04.

Comment: Something to consider: It looks like there will be Arch Linux 32 bit builds in the future.  I've been investigating that to keep my old netbook going after 18.04 ages out. https://archlinux32.org/

Comment: Think Debian is also keeping 32bit for the time, but for now you can keep using 18.04 till end of support or will have to find another Linux distro that supports 32bit.  This will require a clean install, so will have to back up your data first.  Check that your CPU is 32bit only(like a P4).  Might only have an OS that is 32bit, but still need a clean install to go to 64bit OS.

Comment: You've given no details as to your hardware, but I used pentium M & pentium 4 boxes to test Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and other flavors for the last release (2020-August (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) so it's still supported, but in Ubuntu (& *flavors*) you're best with 18.04 whilst support exists. I also test Debian (Debian Buster ran fine too on those same boxes) so I'd go there (as per @crip659's suggestion post Ubuntu)